# Couchdb and Nitrogen

Tags: erlang, couchdb, nitrogen

How to add Key/value pairs to existing couchdb document through nitrogen web framework? 
ecouch:doc_update(DBName,DocId,DocValue) is not returning true when I was trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a proper init of ecouch ?
Try to fetch this document first in development console.

To do this use

```
doc_get/2
doc_get(DatabaseName::string(), DocName::string) -> {ok, Response::json()} | {error,     Reason::term()}
```

This will show you if you init properly connection if not use `init` if it returns document try to update its json and update it using.

```
doc_update/3
doc_update(DatabaseName::string(), DocName::string(), Doc::json()) -> {ok, Response::json()} | {error, Reason::term()}
```

pattern match it on `{ok, _ } = doc_update(..` to see if it will blow up.  If it will blow up you can do `{error, Reason} = doc_update(...` and then just io:format("~p~n", [Reason]), to see the actual reason.

I think you are not doing proper init of ecouch thats all.

ecouch doc:
http://code.google.com/p/ecouch/wiki/APIDocumentation